# LiveData does not show data Instantly on opening app

Tags: android, architecture, android-livedata

## The Issue

I implemented the Android Architecture library and with this I am restoring data from Room Database, with MVVM (Model View View-Model) and whenever I use the observer to view LiveDada every time I start the app there is a noticeable delay when the items from the recycler view loads.

[image: This]

Image illustrates on what I mean when the app stats and the items show delay when they load.

## What I want it to do

What I want to achieve with LiveData is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqs8q.gif) and the way I was able to achieve this is in my Dao I used a Query to get all of the data and pass it as a List rather than using LiveData and then in the Repository convert it to MutableLiveData and then pass it to database and from there observe it as LiveData in my fragment but using this approach actually doesn't update on delete or on insert unless if i restart the app.
Is there any way to fix this issue?
I would much like to use LiveData.

This is my DevicesDao interface:

```
@Dao
public interface DevicesDao {

   @Insert
   void insert(Devices... devices);

   @Query("SELECT * FROM devices")
   LiveData<List<Devices>> getDevices();
   /*
   @Query("SELECT * FROM devices")
   List<Devices> getDevices();
   */
   @Delete
    void delete(Devices... device);

    @Update
    void update(Devices... device);
}
```

Database:

```
@Database(entities = {Devices.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class DevicesDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "devices_registered";

    private static DevicesDatabase instance;

    public abstract DevicesDao devicesDao();

    public static DevicesDatabase getInstance(final Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (DevicesDatabase.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                            context.getApplicationContext(),
                            DevicesDatabase.class,
                            DATABASE_NAME)
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public class DevicesRepository {

    private final DevicesDao devicesDao;

    public DevicesRepository(Application application) {
        DevicesDatabase db = DevicesDatabase.getInstance(application);
        devicesDao = db.devicesDao();
    }

    public void addDevices(Devices devices) {
        new InsertDeviceAsync(devicesDao).execute(devices);
    }

    public void updateDevice(Devices devices) {
        new UpdateDeviceAsync(devicesDao).execute(devices);
    }

    public void deleteDevice(Devices devices) {
        new DeleteDeviceAsync(devicesDao).execute(devices);
    }

    //Gets all data from SQLite
    public LiveData<List<Devices>> getAllDevices() {
        return devicesDao.getDevices();
    }

    /*
    public LiveData<List<Devices>> getAllDevices() {
        MutableLiveData<List<Devices>> devices = new MutableLiveData<>();
        try {
            devices.setValue(new GetDeviceAsync(devicesDao).execute().get());
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return devices;
    }
    */
}
```

View Model File:

```
public class HomeFragmentViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private final DevicesRepository devicesRepository;
    private LiveData<List<Devices>> devices;

    public HomeFragmentViewModel(@NotNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        devicesRepository = new DevicesRepository(application);
        devices = devicesRepository.getAllDevices();
    }


    public LiveData<List<Devices>> getAllDevices() {
        return devices;
    }

    public void addNewDevice(Devices devices) {
        devicesRepository.addDevices(devices);
    }

    public void deleteDevice(Devices devices) {
        devicesRepository.deleteDevice(devices);
    }

    public void editDevice(Devices devices) {
        devicesRepository.updateDevice(devices);
    }
}
```

And lasty, the observer in my fragment:

```
   ///////Other code
    //Implements ViewModel to HomeFragment
    homeFragmentViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeFragmentViewModel.class);

   homeFragmentViewModel.getAllDevices().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), devicesList -> {

        //Validation tool
        validationUtil = new ValidationUtil(devicesList);

        //Adds to adapter
        adapter.submitList(devicesList);

       /////// Other code
    });
```

Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: I think this should go into code review stackexchange. Your code looks fine and the delay is barely noticeable as you have to initialize the dao and make the query.

Comment: @m0skit0 Okay will go into code review. Thank you!

Comment: have you tried adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()? but you will also need to make a copy of your list locally in your fragment and pass that local list to your adapter.

Comment: @Amirjodat I was trying to avoid having to copy the data to a list in my fragment, but I will try that. And in my recyclerview adapter I use ListAdapter, which doesn't use notifySetDataChanged. Instead it sorts the range based on edited files.

Comment: Update: same results even if adding the adapter with a copy of my list.

Answer (score 0):

New update: When I reset the app data, it loads fine but as soon as I decide to update the code, the issue comes back regardless of that edit I make in Android Studio.